# Is investing in the stock market gambling?

Tags: gambling

Judaism takes a very dim view of gambling.  A gambler may not be a witness in a trial, because he is untrustworthy and is not involved in a productive occupation. [Sanhedrin 3:3]  But is investing in the stock market considered gambling per halacha?  On the one hand, it's exactly the same idea.  On the other hand, it does help the economy, and so has a beneficial effect on society.

Comment: *On the one hand, it's exactly the same idea.* That's a strong statement. There are similarities, sure, but also many differences.

Comment: Does it say anywhere that taking financial risks for a "worthy" cause is not gambling?

Comment: The problem with gambling on dice is theft from the other player who didn't "really" agree to give you money. Here every trade is presumably made with full understanding by both sides. This is just like every business deal ever. I buy wheat and it goes down in price; sad for me.

Comment: Doesn't the "other player" also know he might lose?

Comment: It's not that he doesn't know, it's that he's betting on winning. If anything that might be even more applicable to stocks.

Comment: I heard people who had serious gambling addictions  argue that since people who invest in the stock market are taking a risk they are doing the same thing.

Comment: https://www.koltorah.org/halachah/stocks-a-forbidden-form-of-gambling-according-to-halachah-by-rabbi-yair-manas

Comment: I love Rav Soloveitchik's take.  When you buy stock, you are buying a piece of a company. It's just the purchase of goods, and therefore cannot be considered gambling.

Comment: @DoubleAA That is not the only issue: https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%97%D7%A7_%D7%91%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%94

Comment: @user6781 Yes but the OP already stated that wasn't an issue here ("it does help the economy, and so has a beneficial effect on society")

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi That's the same thing I wrote above. I can't imagine it's unique to Rav Soloveitchik or that anyone would disagree with it.

Comment: @doubleAA I think the more relevant point is the "full understanding" rather than the "immediate ownership". Nafka mina for derivatives